# Can we repack an installed application?

Tags: system-installation

I want to install ubuntu on another computer but the computer does not have an internet connection. so i want to move the application from my laptop to the computer. Can we move it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No.

But, Ubuntu caches most of the downloaded packages under in `/var/cache/apt/archives` directory.

You can copy the content in `/var/cache/apt/archives` to another Ubuntu Computer's same location, and install the apps without downloading again.

Make surem that both computers must run the same version of Ubuntu.

To automate the entire process, you can use [AptOnCD](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/aptoncd/)

Answer (score 6):

## Yes !

You can do so with `dpkg-repack`, which can repack installed applications back into a .deb file. To install it:

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack
```

Then, to use it type

```
sudo dpkg-repack <packagename(s)>
```

Which will give you a .deb file (or multiple files, if you repacked multiple packages) in the current directory, which you can then install on another computer. Note that this will *not* repackage any dependencies of the package (you will have to do that yourself), nor will it back up any configuration or personal user data created by the application.

Comment: This answer should have been accepted.